# Split many ArcGIS rasters in parallel using Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arcgis, raster, arcpy

I am looking to split 10 images into 2 parts each (20 resulting images). The images are 4-band (R,G,B,nIR) NAIP imagery available from [this website](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/). I am using the `arcpy` package from ArcGIS to split one image at a time:

```
import arcpy, os

inws = r'D:\temp\temp_NAIP'  #Contains ~10 .tif images
outws = r'D:\temp\temp_NAIP_tiles'

arcpy.env.workspace = inws
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for ras in rasters:
    arcpy.SplitRaster_management(
        ras, outws, 
        os.path.basename(ras).split('.')[0], 
        split_method='NUMBER_OF_TILES', 
        format='TIFF', 
        num_rasters='1 2',
        overlap=50, units='PIXELS)
```

How can I integrate the `multiprocessing` module into the above script to process, say, 4 images at a time?

Btw, I am aware of a [blog post](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/) that combines `multiprocessing` and `arcpy`, although the examples are specific to vector data and I cannot figure out how to utilize the tools to process imagery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring any resource sharing issues, converting a simple for-loop into multiprocessing is easy to do with a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Try something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import arcpy, os

inws = r'D:\temp\temp_NAIP'  #Contains ~10 .tif images
outws = r'D:\temp\temp_NAIP_tiles'

arcpy.env.workspace = inws    
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

def process_img(ras):
    arcpy.SplitRaster_management(
        ras, outws, 
        os.path.basename(ras).split('.')[0], 
        split_method='NUMBER_OF_TILES',
        format='TIFF', 
        num_rasters='1 2',
        overlap=50, units='PIXELS')

pool = Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(process_img, rasters)
```

So long as `rasters` is an iterable, it should be mappable to a process pool. Keep in mind that each process will "inherit" the parent process' stack, such that each process will use it's own copy of `arcpy.env.workspace`.